# how to separate list with the length of nested list python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a nested list like this:

```
 a = [[0.00069053395], [0.7278625], [0.8591849, 0.86290157, 0.8703022], [0.9041279, 0.9102304, 0.91197634], [0.93096334, 0.93327045], [0.9456768, 0.95339334], [0.98164046, 0.9836741]]
```

and another list like below:

```
b = ['/home/shape/13.jpg', '/home/shape/5.jpg', '/home/shape/6.jpg', '/home/shape/0.jpg', '/home/shape/2.jpg', '/home/shape/1.jpg', '/home/shape/7.jpg', '/home/shape/11.jpg', '/home/cuts/shape/10.jpg', '/home/shape/4.jpg', '/home/shape/14.jpg', '/home/shape/12.jpg', '/home/shape/16.jpg', '/home/shape/8.jpg']
```

I want to make the list `b` similar to nested list `a`, with its length of its elements.

Expected output:

```
c = [['/home/shape/13.jpg'],['/home/shape/5.jpg'],['/home/shape/6.jpg', '/home/shape/0.jpg', '/home/shape/2.jpg'],['/home/shape/1.jpg', '/home/shape/7.jpg', '/home/shape/11.jpg'],['/home/cuts/shape/10.jpg', '/home/shape/4.jpg'],['/home/shape/14.jpg', '/home/shape/12.jpg'],['/home/shape/16.jpg', '/home/shape/8.jpg']]
```

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
c = []
count = 0
for i in a:
     c.append(b[count:count+len(i)])
     count = count+len(i)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[['/home/shape/13.jpg'], ['/home/shape/5.jpg'], ['/home/shape/6.jpg', 
 '/home/shape/0.jpg', '/home/shape/2.jpg'], ['/home/shape/1.jpg', 
 '/home/shape/7.jpg', '/home/shape/11.jpg'], ['/home/cuts/shape/10.jpg', 
 '/home/shape/4.jpg'], ['/home/shape/14.jpg', '/home/shape/12.jpg'], 
 ['/home/shape/16.jpg', '/home/shape/8.jpg']]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) built-in function with list comprehension:

```
it = iter(b)

[[next(it) for _ in l] for l in a]
```

output:

```
[['/home/shape/13.jpg'],
 ['/home/shape/5.jpg'],
 ['/home/shape/6.jpg', '/home/shape/0.jpg', '/home/shape/2.jpg'],
 ['/home/shape/1.jpg', '/home/shape/7.jpg', '/home/shape/11.jpg'],
 ['/home/cuts/shape/10.jpg', '/home/shape/4.jpg'],
 ['/home/shape/14.jpg', '/home/shape/12.jpg'],
 ['/home/shape/16.jpg', '/home/shape/8.jpg']]
```